# ag-grid valueGetter with rowgroup

Tags: ag-grid

I am using rowGroup for 2 fields in my grid.  Normally no row data would be seen for the group leaf, but when i add valueFormatter to a fields data is showing up in the group leaf.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a check the for params.value before the formatting resolved the issue